# Discrepancy Between Predicted and Observed Impact of Parameter Change in Multivariable Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Given:
$$ 
\mathbf{a} = [a_1, a_2] \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{b} = [b_1, b_2] 
$$

The expression for $\mathbf{c}$:
$$ 
\mathbf{c} = 3\mathbf{a}^3 - \mathbf{b}^2 
$$

We need to find the partial derivative of $\mathbf{c}$ with respect to $\mathbf{a}$. Let's denote $\mathbf{c} = [c_1, c_2]$. Then:

$$
\frac{\partial c_1}{\partial a_1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_1} (3a_1^3 - b_1^2) = 9a_1^2
$$
$$
\frac{\partial c_2}{\partial a_2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_2} (3a_2^3 - b_2^2) = 9a_2^2
$$

So the partial derivatives of $\mathbf{c}$ with respect to $\mathbf{a}$ are:
$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{c}}{\partial \mathbf{a}} = \begin{bmatrix} 9a_1^2 \\ 9a_2^2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

In our specific case where $\mathbf{a} = [2.0, 3.0]$, the derivatives would be:
$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{c}}{\partial \mathbf{a}} = \begin{bmatrix} 36.0 \\ 81.0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

These derivatives represent the expected impact on $\mathbf{c}$ when adding 1 unit to each component of $\mathbf{a}$. But if we manually calculate $\mathbf{c}$ when $\mathbf{a}+1$ that is $\mathbf{a} = [3.0, 4.0]$ and $\mathbf{b} = [6.0, 4.0]$ - keeping it unchanged - the observed result differs from the expected.

$$ \text{Expected Change} = \begin{bmatrix} 36.0 \\ 81.0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ \text{Observed Change} = \begin{bmatrix} 57.0 \\ 111.0 \end{bmatrix} $$

The observed change differs from the expected change. This suggests a discrepancy between the predicted and actual impacts on $\mathbf{c}$. Why?